# Change home of WSL to /mnt/c/Users/YourWindowsUser

Tags: linux, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

### What I'm trying to do

I tried to edit the home dir of the windows subsystem (in my case Ubuntu) to my default User in Windows.
Why? Because I want to replace Cygwin or at least check if it's viable to replace Cygwin. Please let's focus on the how, not why. I'm also aware that commanding windows via the Subsystem can cause write/read permission issues AFAIK.

### The problem(s)

I tried to modify passwd with vim, but I have read that this can cause issues and it's supposed to be far safer to manipulate it by commands. Luckily the command for the job exists:

`sudo usermod --home /mnt/c/Users/User CurrentUser`

However, when I enter it the output is:

`usermod: user CurrentUser is currently used by process 4`

But: process 4 is bash.

```
User@Machinename:~$ ps -A
PID TTY          TIME CMD
  1 ?        00:00:00 init
  3 tty1     00:00:00 init
  4 tty1     00:00:00 bash
 39 tty1     00:00:00 ps
```

1. When I kill (`kill -9 4`) it, the Subsystem dies, obviously.
2. When I try changing the user to root (`sudo -i`), it does not list CurrentUser when I enter `who` or any other "who is logged in"-type commands.

Has anyone figured out how to do this, that when I enter `cd` in the subsystem, it brings me to `/mnt/c/User/CurrentUser`?
What am I doing wrong?

**Note**:This is a [repost of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51216096/change-home-of-wsl-to-mnt-c-users-yourwindowsuser/51217412#51217412) on SO since it was suggested I may find an answer here if I repost it. I'll just link it in case somebody finds one or the other resource and is led here since superuser is the right place for it.

Comment: Why do you post same question and answer in Stackoverflow and in Superuser?

Comment: Because it was put on hold there ("you may get an answer on superuser"), and my answer is more or less documentation of a possible solution, but not optimal. I still want to know how to change a users home directory in WSL.

Comment: WSL is under current development, doesn't support file permission correctly in Linux & Win world. Windows uses AppData & LocalAppData but Linux doesn't. So your procedure may colflict both worlds fatally ;)

Answer (score 1):

I found a better workaround by not logging in as USERNAME, but logging in as root (temporarily) instead.  Here are the commands I used on my system, running ubuntu on a current Windows 10 build 19043.1165:

In an elevated PS prompt

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> ubuntu.exe config --default-user root
```

Start ubuntu, and run:

```
usermod --home /mnt/c/Users/SHORTNA~1/ USERNAME
```

- Note that if you have spaces in your windows username, you will need to use the path with the ~ in it.  You can find it by opening a command prompt and using `dir /x`.

Next return to your elevated powershell and run:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> ubuntu.exe config --default-user USERNAME
```

Next time you start your ubuntu shell, it should have the right home directory.  If you're using another distro, you should have a similar command (opensuse-42, or sles-12 for example).

Comment: A couple of notes.  While I don't recommend this at all (for reasons I'll cover in an answer), in 2021 it's not necessary to change the *default* user for the WSL.  Just run `wsl -u root` and it will start Ubuntu as root.  Then there's no need to change it back.

Answer (score 0):

## This answer is not optimal, only a workaround

### The other option

I did not figure it out, however a workaround for changing the default users root would be creating a new user with a different home directory.
Since I do not subscribe to an approach, but rather to a solution, this option was satisfactory for the problem discribed.

### How it can be done

This [can be accomplished](https://www.lifewire.com/create-users-useradd-command-3572157) by typing:

`sudo useradd -m -d /mnt/c/Users/windowsUser YourNewUserName`

Switching the user:

To the new user: `su - YourNewUserName`

Back to default: `su - YourDefaultUserName`

### Circumstantial problems

Switching users requires root privileges. If you don't know your `su` password ([which is different](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109944/why-is-the-sudo-password-different-than-the-su-root-password) from the `sudo` password), type:

`sudo -i`

and authenticate with your `sudo` password. Then set the new password, with

`passwd`

This solution is IMO even better/cleaner, since to control your windows user with WSL  easily by switching users back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

An old question that got bumped today, so I'll take a stab at it with the latest information.

First up, just don't do this, *especially* on WSL2.  The performance of WSL2 with files stored on a Windows drive is abysmal.  When using the *ext4* filesystem that comes with WSL2, performance is near-par with Windows or Linux.  When accessing files on a Windows drive, it can be more than 10 times slower (sometimes *much* more).

Second, if you simply must do this, two things to keep in mind:

- The `wsl` command gives you a lot more flexibility than was available when this question was originally asked 3 years ago.  You can easily handle this case by:

  - Logging out of your current user (so you don't run into the "in use" problem)
  - From PowerShell or CMD, run `wsl -u root`.  This will start the WSL instance as the root user user.
  - Perform the modifications you need (e.g. `usermod`)
  - Exit WSL and restart as the normal user

  No `sudo`, `su`, or password mess to deal with.
- Second, please note that there are nuances to how permissions are mapped between your Windows drive and the Linux filesystem.  By default, `chmod` and equivalents in WSL have no effect on a file or directory on a Windows drive.  This can cause problems with many utilities under Linux, especially `git` and `rsync`.

  WSL can be modified to "pretend" to set and honor Linux-permissions on files by creating a file named `/etc/wsl.conf` with the following contents:

  ```
  [automount]
  options = "metadata"
  ```

  Please see [this Microsoft doc regarding permissions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/file-permissions) and [this one regarding wsl.conf](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#configure-per-distro-launch-settings-with-wslconf) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Case in point: Why would you ever use WSL instead of just Linux when you have to deal with Windows kernel anyway

Comment: @BlkPengu That's easy -- I *like* the Windows desktop experience, but I'm also a command-line junkie, and Linux shines there, IMHO. The Interop between the two is very impressive to me.  With WSL1, Linux syscalls are translated to the Windows kernel, but with WSL2, it's running a real Linux kernel (that you can compile yourself if you want).  And let's say you dual-booted (or even if you were running "pure Linux") -- It still wouldn't be a good idea to put `$HOME` on an NTFS drive.  It's probably easier to do this with WSL than it would with dual-boot, but not recommended either way.